# ng-if change value in view

Tags: angularjs, angular-ng-if

I'm new in angularJS, here is my issue:
 I would like to know what is the syntax for doing this:
i would like to put the value to `'0'` if `user.fields[5].value=undefined` I tried this with `ng-if` but it's not working, i don't know the syntax and i don't know if `ng-if` is appropriate for doing this. Maybe `ng-init` is better, i don't know can you help me pls ?

Here is my code:

```
ng-if="user.fields[5].value==undefined[user.fields[5].value='0']">{{user.fields[5].value}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this like that :

This should work even though i won't advise it :

```
<div ng-if="user.fields[5].value==undefined">
   <div ng-init="user.fields[5].value='0'">{{user.fields[5].value}}</div>
</div>
```

The proper way to do this is in the controller using $watch :

```
$scope.$watch(function(){return user.fields[5];}, function(newValue){
   if(newValue===undefined){
       user.fields[5].value='0';
   }
});
```

But how are you getting the undefined in that field ? You shouldn't need that

EDIT : About your comment with the API :

Then you shouldn't do that in your controller neither in the view. You should do that in the service layer with something that look like :

```
//service layer return the promise
return $http.get('API...').then(function(response){
    var data = response.data;
    [.. format your data ...]
    return data;// don't forget to return it so your controller will have those formatted data : 
});
//controller layer
myService.getData().then(function(data){
    // CLEAN data!!!!
});
```

Comment: Yes you are right, but i received data from API and data are not display as i wish so i need to do some modifications

Comment: Then there is a better way to do this by using promise chain : look into my edit.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your post ! it was very helpfull !

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `ng-if` is the good way of doing it !

As you can see [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf), `ng-if` creates or removes `DOM` elements, like  `<div>` or `<p>` ...

I think the simplest way to do it is to do it inside your controller.

Comment: i can't do it inside the controller because i didn t ' indicate in my post but we are inside an ng-repeat, so it will not working i as want, it will not iterate in the loop of ng-repeat.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally AngularJS built-in *directives* like `ng-if`, `ng-switch`, `ng-init`, etc. are used in DOM, on basis of conditions and work on assignments except that of `ng-class`.

If you need to assign any `model` a value, you *should* do it in `.js` file only. And once assigned, you can use it in the HTML DOM.

Hope it is clear to you.